# Image / video / sound management application

Tags: video, images, media-manager, digital-asset-management

I'm looking for an application in which I can catalogue images/videos and possibly sounds.

I'd like to be able to:

- Allow me to define custom fields for the content types
- Import content via CSV. This should allow me to map CSV field values to the correct fields. Filenames contained in the CSV file should allow files to be loaded into the application. (If this is accessible by an API, then that will be acceptable too)
- Extraction of meta data when importing content
- Search by fields (title/description etc.), keywords, tags and custom fields
- Preferably non-commercial
- Export to CSV
- Some sort of API / plugin system to allow me to query the data inside and pull content depending on data I pass programatically

I don't care if it runs as a web app, an application or whatever. It can work on either Windows or Linux. (Please don't suggest Drupal!)

Comment: I don't understand `fussed` very well, I suppose it means `don't mind`, does it? The CSV part seems the most specialized, I'm used to see this on web-apps, but that would mean that you need to somewhat upload the media. Is uploading a no-go? It's not clear if you mean local media or online media.